# Stringr: extracting all matches from strings in a data.frame column. Data.frame and vector of searched strings very large (>10k)

Tags: r, stringr

**EDIT:** I have a data frame wherein column 1 has id on some texts and column 2 has the text itself as strings. I have a set of multiple words and the task is to have `stringr` count the number of times each word is found within the texts. The words are to be supplied as fixed, not as regex. 
Two problems stand out: 
(1) How to supply a vector containing multiple words as a fixed (not regex) pattern? 
(2) How to append the findings to the data frame? 
(3) How to do it for very large data?

A previous answer from user @akrun answered points (1) and (2), but (3) is still an issue. Here is a reproducible example.

```r
## create a very large data.frame with the text column to be analyzed
doc_number <- c()
doc_text <- c()

for(i in 1:60000){

# generate many random strings mentioning 'proposals'
doc_number[i] <- paste0("doc_",i)
set.seed(i+3)
doc_text[i] <- paste0("This is about proposal ", "(", sample(1000:9999, 1), "/", sample(letters, 1),")",
                      " and about proposal ", "(", sample(1000:9999, 1), "/", sample(letters, 1),")")

}
docs_example_df <- data.frame(doc_number, doc_text)

head(docs_example_df) # resulting df has 'doc_text' column which mentions proposals
> head(docs_example_df)
  doc_number                                                    doc_text
1      doc_1 This is about proposal (6623/k) and about proposal (3866/c)
2      doc_2 This is about proposal (3254/k) and about proposal (2832/u)
3      doc_3 This is about proposal (7964/j) and about proposal (1940/n)
4      doc_4 This is about proposal (8582/g) and about proposal (3753/o)
5      doc_5 This is about proposal (4254/b) and about proposal (5686/l)
6      doc_6 This is about proposal (2588/f) and about proposal (9786/c)


# create a very large vector of 'proposals' I want to extract from doc_text
my_proposals <- c()

for(i in 1:20000){

  set.seed(i+8)
  my_proposals[i] <- paste0("proposal ", "(", sample(1000:9999, 1), "/", sample(letters, 1),")")

}

head(my_proposals) # long list of 'proposals' I wish to locate
> head(my_proposals)
[1] "proposal (2588/f)" "proposal (1490/i)" "proposal (2785/b)" "proposal (5545/z)" "proposal (6988/j)" "proposal (1264/i)"
```

The previous answer by @akrun (see below) recommended several solutions which worked for a small data.frame. But in such >20k objects the functions either jam or give error such as:

```r
Problem with mutate() input matches. x Incorrectly nested parentheses in regexp pattern. (U_REGEX_MISMATCHED_PAREN)
```

So, in short, how to apply a very long list of vectors to an also very long data.frame and store extracted matches in something like a column-list in the data.frame?

Thanks everyone

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We could `paste` them together and wrap it in `regex` instead of `fixed`.  In `dplyr` 1.0.0, there are multiple functions introduced and one of them is `across`

```
library(dplyr) #1.0.0
library(stringr)
test_df %>%
  mutate(matches = str_extract_all(text,
                pattern = regex(str_c(keywords, collapse = "|"))))
```

---

If we need the final expected output, after creating the `list` column in `matches`, `unnest` to expand the rows, get the `count` and reshape it to 'wide' format with `pivot_wider`

```
library(tidyr)
test_df %>%
   mutate(matches = str_extract_all(test_df$text, pattern = regex(str_c(keywords, collapse = "|")))) %>% 
   unnest(c(matches)) %>% 
   count(across(doc_id:matches)) %>% 
   pivot_wider(names_from = matches, values_from = n, values_fill = list(n = 0))
# A tibble: 4 x 6
#  doc_id text                                           water alcohol gasoline   h2o
#  <chr>  <chr>                                          <int>   <int>    <int> <int>
#1 doc1   This text refers to water                          1       0        0     0
#2 doc2   This text refers to water and alcohol              1       1        0     0
#3 doc4   This text refers to gasoline and more gasoline     0       0        2     0
#4 doc5   This text refers to (h2o)                          0       0        0     1
```

If we have a `dplyr` < 1.0.0, instead of `across` just specify the names of the columns in `count`

```
... %>%
count(doc_id, text, matches)
... %>%
```

Or convert the column names to symbols and evaluate

```
 ... %>%
   count(!!! rlang::syms(names(.)))
... %>%
```

---

In the above method 'doc3' is removed as there were no matches.  If we need to keep it, specify the `keep_empty = TRUE` in `unnest`

```
test_df %>%
    mutate(matches = str_extract_all(test_df$text, 
          pattern = regex(str_c(keywords, collapse = "|")))) %>% 
    unnest(c(matches), keep_empty = TRUE) %>% 
    count(across(doc_id:matches)) %>% 
    mutate(n = replace(n, is.na(matches), 0)) %>% 
    pivot_wider(names_from = matches, values_from = n, values_fill = list(n = 0)) %>%
    select(-`NA`)
# A tibble: 5 x 6
#  doc_id text                                           water alcohol gasoline   h2o
#  <chr>  <chr>                                          <dbl>   <dbl>    <dbl> <dbl>
#1 doc1   This text refers to water                          1       0        0     0
#2 doc2   This text refers to water and alcohol              1       1        0     0
#3 doc3   This text refers to alcoolh                        0       0        0     0
#4 doc4   This text refers to gasoline and more gasoline     0       0        2     0
#5 doc5   This text refers to (h2o)                          0       0        0     1
```

---

In addition to the above method, an easier option is to use `str_count`

```
library(purrr)
map_dfc(set_names(keywords, keywords), ~ 
      str_count(test_df$text, .x)) %>% 
   bind_cols(test_df, .)
#  doc_id                                           text water alcohol gasoline (h2o)
#1   doc1                      This text refers to water     1       0        0     0
#2   doc2          This text refers to water and alcohol     1       1        0     0
#3   doc3                    This text refers to alcoolh     0       0        0     0
#4   doc4 This text refers to gasoline and more gasoline     0       0        2     0
#5   doc5                      This text refers to (h2o)     0       0        0     1
```

---

Or using `base R`

```
test_df[keywords] <-  lapply(keywords, function(x) 
        lengths(regmatches(test_df$text, gregexpr(x, test_df$text))))
```

---

Although `str_extract` is vectorized for `pattern`, it would be in such a way that the `pattern` length would be the same as the column length and it would be doing a correspoinding extraction

Comment: @arkun : which package includes the command 'across' that you used in the 'count' command in your third bloc of code?

Comment: It is from `dplyr` 1.0.0

Comment: is there an equivalent in the tidyverse package?

Comment: @Rafael these are all tidyverse.  `dplyr` is part of tidyverse.  It is from the new version as the older functions could get deprecated

Comment: @Rafael you can check [here](https://www.tidyverse.org/packages/) for the packages in tidyverse

Comment: got it. My version was actually the 0.8.5 still.

Comment: @Rafael there is only a single line that needs to be changed i.e. you can still use `%>% count(doc_id, text, matches) %>%` it is just that the range of columns (`:`) can be wrapped with `across` instead of typing each column or `count(!!! rlang::syms(names(.)))`

Comment: Is there any reason why the supplied `keywords` could malfunction? For the mock example it worked fine (btw, thanks!). My real `keywords` vector however is 18k words long, and has characters such as `"902 (ix) of 9 december 1954"` and `"73/2 of 10 october 2018"` . I keep getting error messages about 'incorrectly nested parentheses' like: `Problem with mutate() input matches.
x Incorrectly nested parentheses in regexp pattern. (U_REGEX_MISMATCHED_PAREN)`

Comment: @Rafael if there are a lots of words, I would use the `map_dfc` or `lapply` in the last two code blocks as there is a limit for doing the `|`.   I would use the `str_c`method only if the number of words are within 100

Comment: scale really seems to matter. I keep getting the same 'Incorrectly nested parentheses in regexp pattern. (U_REGEX_MISMATCHED_PAREN)' warning even after using the 3rd and 4th solutions. The code would run ok if the vector was smaller, but the original 18k length leads to the same warning. I will re-work the question on top so that it tackles the matter of 'thousand-word-long' vectors more clearly.